# Using HERE in an embedded web browser

Tags: here-api

I've just started looking at using the HERE Javascript API and wish to display the map in an embedded web browser. (I'm using Delphi, however this problem might apply to any development tool that supports embedded browsers). I'm using the quick start example:

https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics/quick-start.html

The HERE logo displays in the bottom right, and the copyright notice in the bottom left, but the map does not display. Identical HTML being loaded from a file displays OK in Edge.

I have an entry in the registry in:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION

For my application, and have tried values of 11011, 11001, 99999, 9999 and 11001, however the result is all the same. Are embedded browsers not supported, or is there something else I need to do?

**EDIT:**

Doing the same thing in a Visual Studio C++ MFC app results in the same behaviour

**EDIT 2:**

Now that Delphi has support for embedding Edge browser - still the same issue, i.e. HERE logo and copyright shows, but no map. Can someone from HERE actually respond and indicate whether it's even possible to use an embedded browser? (MFC app which uses Edge didn't work, either)

**EDIT 3:**

A colleague suggested opening the DevTools and checking the console for errors - here's the result:

[image]

Comment: try using 11000

Comment: @fisi-pjm Same result

Answer (score 0):

This is what I found while making it work in the webbrowser control of MS Access (embedded IE). You have to use P2D engine and legacy javascript files from Here maps. I did and now the map is shown but it's not draggable yet, don't know why.

I put 11001 in my registry but I also add this line to my html:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Then you need at least these links to have legacy support (in this particular order):

```
<script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core-legacy.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-service.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-service-legacy.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

And this option in the map initialization:

```
engineType: H.map.render.RenderEngine.EngineType.P2D,
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however none of it helped in my case. Using H.map.render.RenderEngine.EngineType.P2D actually prevents it from displaying in Edge (i.e. in the browser), as well.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience.

Currently we are supporting the below browsers for the javascript api.

Edge 17+
Firefox (latest)
Google Chrome (latest)
Apple Safari 11+
The same is mentioned in the below api document. https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/3.1.34.1/dev_guide/topics/browser-support.html

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that using `NavigateToString` in `ICoreWebView2` does not work with HERE.

The solution was to use a file for the HTML, and use `Navigate` with a URL of, for example: `file://C:\HTML\Here.html`